# Asp.net Label control maxlenght

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one asp label which I have bind with database using eval but the data i have in database is paragraph and I just want to print 2-3 lines of that paragraph so any one can help.

What I have tried:

```
<asp:label id="lDesc" runat ="server" text ='<%# (Eval("Description") .Length>=100) ? Eval("Description").SubString(0,100) : Eval("Description") %>'></asp:Label>
```

Comment: Can you post an example of some code that you have tried?

Comment: <asp:label id="lDesc" runat ="server" text ='<%# (Eval("Description") .Length>=100) ? Eval("Description").SubString(0,100) :Eval("Description") %>'></asp:Label> i tried css style also I get error on length

Comment: That code seems fine. What is the error you're getting? If it is `runat` server you could also probably set the text value in the code-behind.

Comment: I am getting red mark on length

Comment: If the code you pasted was exactly the code you have, there are spacing errors. Here is what it should be. `<asp:label id="lDesc" runat ="server" text ='<%# (Eval("Description").Length >= 100) ? Eval("Description").SubString(0,100) : Eval("Description") %>'></asp:Label>`

Comment: Why not just select the first X amount of characters in the field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply select the first 100 characters of that field in the database. Something like this:

```
SELECT LEFT([your field], 100) as 'your field'
```